# React - How to change material icon with an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to change the material icon from **add** to **remove** with an on click event in React. To clear up some confusion, this has nothing to do with classes, it's to do with the material icon that actually displays. Add is a plus icon, I need to change it from add to remove, which is a subtract icon.

```
handleClick() {
    console.log('test');    
}

render() {
    <div>
        <i className="material-icons mobile" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>add</i>
    </div> 
}
```

The above works console outputs test perfectly fine, I just have no idea how to approach this. Done some research online and can't find anything about this. Could use with some insight or ideas for an approach to this.

Comment: So you're trying to change css-class `className="material-icons mobile"` on the click? Just to make it a bit more clearer.

Comment: Hi Vahdet, no. I'm trying to change the <i>add</i> to <i>remove</i>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by setting state. Something like this:

```
state = { icon: true }

handleClick = e => {
    const { icon } = this.state
    this.setState({ icon: !icon })   
}

render() {
    const { icon } = this.state
    return(
        <i className='large material-icons' onClick={this.handleClick}>
            { icon ? 'add' : 'remove'}
        </i>
    )

}
```

Comment: new_value is going to be undefined in handleClick

Comment: Yes, I was assuming OP could fill in the value himself. I have made it more clear now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, it's nothing to do with classes, it's to do with the material icon that actually displays. Add is a plus icon, I need to change it from add to remove, which is a subtract icon.

Comment: @Edward I have updated my answer to what you're asking for.

Comment: It works, thanks! I just had to change plusIcon: true to icon: true.

Answer (score 1):

Improving the last answer:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { icon: true };
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({ icon: !this.state.icon })   
}

render() {
    <i className='large material-icons' onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        { this.state.icon ? 'add' : 'remove' }
    </i>
}
```